# Why can I assign a List<T> to an IEnumerable<T>, but not an ICollection<T> or IList<T>

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 types, `IFoo`, and `Foo` defined as

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void run()
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public void run() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I am able to assign a `List<Foo>` to an `IEnumerable<IFoo>`, but not an `ICollection<IFoo>` nor an `IList<IFoo>`.

```
IEnumerable<IFoo> fooEnumerable = new List<Foo>();// works fine
ICollection<IFoo> fooCollection = new List<Foo>();// doesn't work
IList<IFoo>       fooList       = new List<Foo>();// doesn't work
```

Why is that? What allows an `IEnumerable` to not care about what type it's comprised of, while `ICollection` and `IList` do care?

Comment: There are numerous possible duplicates. Search on c# list covariance for more.

Comment: The basic point is that your `List<Foo>` *is not* an `IList<IFoo>`. The former can only accept `Foo` (and Foo-derived) objects. The latter can accept *any* object that implements `IFoo`. Notice the fundamental problem (a problem which `IEnumerable<IFoo>` does not have).

Comment: The problem is that if you have a reference of type IList<IFoo>, you could use its own interface methods to Add an object of type TextFoo, where TextFoo : IFoo. Since the actual object only accepts list items that implement Foo (which TextFoo doesn't), that won't work.

Comment: Whoever voted to re-open: please provide explanation why do you believe linked question does not answer this one.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram what makes IEnumerable different?

Comment: You cannot add items to an IEnumerable. Imagine you have `IList<Fruit> list = new List<Apple>();` *If that compiled*, there would be nothing preventing you from having `list.Add(new Orange());`. Orange is a Fruit, you have an IList of Fruit, you should be able to add it. Problem: the actual list object only holds Apples. IEnumerable<Fruit>, on the other hand, does not support adds. You can safely reference a list of Apples via an IEnumerable of Fruits because there's no chance you'll try to put a non-Apple into that list via the IEnumerable reference.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram How then are we able to know that at compile time? Is there some magic "Covariant"  attribute that IEnumerable has?

Comment: Yes. Search IEnumerable<out T>.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Thanks for all of the info. I wasn't aware of that, and it makes things much more clear.